# vaadin RegexpValidator regex

Tags: java, regex, vaadin

I am using vaadins builtin RegexpValidator to check for valid form fields.I have a description field that can have any charater as long as it's not empty.Initialy i was using ".+" which pretty much worked but when i converted that field from TextField to TextArea it didn't match my strings anymore as ".+" doesn't check for newlines or blank spaces.

I have tried doing "(.|\n|\r)+" but that includes writing a blank space or a newline aswell.

I need only to make sure that i have entered atleast one character it doesn't matter what.
Normally with regex you can check for blanks with "^\s*$" but vaadins RegexpValidator  result must match your string so what i am looking is basicaly the opposite of "^\s*$" ? but including atleast one character? RegexpValidator is really confusing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow a pure whitespace text you can use

```
[\s\S]+
```

`\s` a whitespace character

`\S` a non whitespace character

that would match at least one character and would also match newlines, because they are included in `\s`

If you want to have **at least one Non-whitespace character** you can use

```
^\s*\S
```

That would check for 0 or more whitespaces at the start of the string (this would cover leading newlines) and it would be successful when it finds the first non whitespace.

Comment: yes but this means a user can write a blank space and pass aswell right? i want to allow bland and whitespace characters,BUT as long as there is atleast something written there,that is non whitespace characters

Comment: @sokie, I was not sure if you wanted to allow this or not. I already extended my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your update,it was indeed correct.I was almost there with ^\s*$...still got to better my regex skills apparently